# How do I parse the query portion of a URI in Ruby 1.8?

Tags: ruby, parsing, uri, ruby-1.8

In Ruby 1.8, using the URI standard library, I can parse

```
http://au.easyroommate.com/content/common/listing_detail.aspx?code=H123456789012&from=L123456789012345
```

using `URI.split` to get

```
["http", nil, "au.easyroommate.com", nil, nil,
"/content/common/listing_detail.aspx", nil, 
"code=H123456789012&from=L123456789012345", nil]
```

But is it possible to get the `H123456789012` bit from the query portion without using my own hackery (eg splitting by `&` and then getting the bit that matches `/code.(.*)/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the **[CGI::parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI.html#M000108)** method

```
params = CGI::parse("query_string")
  # {"name1" => ["value1", "value2", ...],
  #  "name2" => ["value1", "value2", ...], ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Rack::Utils` which has a method called `parse_nested_query` which you could pass in the query string from the URL:

```
Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(uri.query_string)
```

This will then return a `Hash` object representing the query string allowing you to gain access to the `code`.

Comment: Turns out Rack is part of the standard library, not a gem. This was a surprise to me.

Comment: Rack is a gem, it isn't part of Ruby's standard library (and this is a good thing).

Comment: @Mauricio: You're right. I'd forgotten I had had it installed.